# Gulp not including Kendo file

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, gulp

We are using Gulp command to build our application. When we run the build command "Gulp Stage"  for our app kendo files are not getting included and build doesn't finish. It just hangs. If I remove Kendo files from package.json it's getting built properly.  Please find the package.json file

```
{
  "name": "ProjectName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "AngularJS Web Project Boilerplate",
  "scripts": {
    "init": "npm install",
    "install": "bower install",
    "test": "karma start"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-jsdoc": "~0.1.1",
    "cli-color": "~0.3.2",
    "commander": "~2.5.0",
    "del": "^0.1.3",
    "gulp": "^3.8.10",
    "gulp-angular-filesort": "^1.0.4",
    "gulp-angular-htmlify": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^1.5.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-bytediff": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-cache": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.5.1",
    "gulp-docco": "^0.0.4",
    "gulp-filelog": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-inject": "^1.0.2",
    "gulp-jscs": "^1.1.2",
    "gulp-jsdoc": "~0.1.4",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.7.1",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^0.8.0",
    "gulp-load-utils": "^0.0.4",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.11",
    "gulp-minify-html": "^0.1.4",
    "gulp-msbuild": "^0.2.4",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^0.5.2",
    "gulp-rev": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "^0.3.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.1.5",
    "gulp-task-listing": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-watch": "^1.0.7",
    "gulp-zip": "^2.0.2",
    "handlebars": "~2.0.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^0.4.0",
    "karma": "^0.12.24",
    "karma-chai": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.5",
    "karma-cli": "0.0.4",
    "karma-mocha": "^0.1.9",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-xml-reporter": "^0.1.4",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "merge-stream": "^0.1.6",
    "mocha": "^1.21.5",
    "q": "~1.0.1"
  },
  "paths": {
    "app": "./app/",
    "aspnet": [
      "./bin/**/*.dll",
      "./Global.asax",
      "./Web.config",
      "./packages.config"
    ],
    "css": [
      "./content/**/*.css"
    ],
    "build": "./build/",
    "examplesjs": "./app/**/*.example.js",
    "docsexamples": "./docs/examples",
    "docsjsdoc": "./docs/jsdoc",
    "fonts": [
      "./bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/**/*.*"
    ],
    "html": "./app/**/*.html",
    "htmltemplates": "./app/**/*.template.html",
    "htmlviews": "./app/**/*.view.html",
    "images": [
      "./content/images/**/*"
    ],
    "index": "./app/layout/index.html",
    "js": [
      "./app/**/*module.js",
      "./app/**/*.provider.js",
      "./app/**/*.service.js",
      "./app/**/*.config.js",
      "./app/**/*.store.js",
      "./app/**/*.run.js",
      "./app/**/*.js",
      "!./app/**/*.example.js",
      "!./app/**/*.spec.js"
    ],
    "solution": "../BC.Web.Seed.sln",
    "stage": "./build/stage/",
    "stagezip": "./build/stage.zip",
"vendorcss": [
  "./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "./bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
  "./bower_components/toastr/toastr.css",
  "./bower_components/select2/select2.css",
  "./bower_components/kendo/styles/kendo.common.min.css",
  "./bower_components/kendo/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css"

],
"vendorjs": [
  "./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "./bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js",
  "./bower_components/angular/angular.min.js",
  "./bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js",
  "./bower_components/angular-local-storage/dist/angular-local-storage.min.js",
  "./bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js",
  "./bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js",
  "./bower_components/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js",
  "./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
  "./bower_components/toastr/toastr.min.js",
  "./bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.min.js",
  "./bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js",
  "./bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js",
  "./bower_components/select2/select2.min.js",
  "./bower_components/angular-ui-select2/src/select2.js",
  "./bower_components/angularjs-geolocation/src/geolocation.js",
  "./bower_components/angular-modal-service/angular-modal-service.min.js",
    "./bower_components/kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js",  
    "./bower_components/kendo/js/kendo.angular.min",     
    "./bower_components/kendo/js/kendo.web.min.js"
],
"vendorjs_ie8": [
  "./bower_components/html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.min.js",
  "./bower_components/respond/dest/respond.min.js"
]
  },

 "dependencies": {
    "gulp-rev-replace": "^0.3.4"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the exact same problem. It started working when I replaced kendo.all.min.js by the unminified version: kendo.all.js. It takes a minute though!